# Embedding a iOS URL Scheme on a website

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, pdf, titanium

im currently developing an iOS app, in which the users presses a button inside the app, this button shall then be a simple  link to an external website, this website shall then use a URL Scheme that starts the GoodReader app (if installed) on the iPad.

But, what exactly do I throw in the source code of the page, the app links to?? I found out hat the URL scheme for the goodreader would be

url=@"ghttp://www.example.com/myfile.pdf"

But how does the rest of the code look like?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using titanium, you may try the following:

Upon button click, invoke

`Ti.Platform.openURL("ghttp://www.example.com/myfile.pdf");`

If the URL scheme is correct and the google reader app has been installed, it will open the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need in your IBAction that catchs the button pressed action:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ghttp://www.example.com/myfile.pdf"];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
{
    NSLog(@"Cannot open url: %@",[url description]);
}
```

Comment: Does this have to embedded in the application (the function of the button) or can this action be runned via a script on an external websites (Such as the open telephone, or mail functions) ?

Answer (score 0):

- In your ViewController.m file, you add this function

  -(IBAction)openGoogleReader:(id)sender
  {
      NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ghttp://www.example.com/myfile.pdf"];

  ```
  if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url])
  {
      NSLog(@"Cannot open url: %@",[url description]);
  }
  ```

  }

Then in the .xib file (or in storyboard) of this ViewController, you hold the Ctrl key and press on the left-button of your mouse and drag to the ViewController object (yellow) and select openGoogleReader: in the "Sent Event". You can see an example below

[image]